# how to get just one character form a string contained in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare each character of the string `num` with each digit of the strings contained in `computer_guesses`.
I must use the numbers as strings.
I tried to run this code but the output was:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Probably i'm just missing the syntax, i'm sure that it can be made without using the function `split(word)` .

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]


computer_guesses = ["12345", "67890"]
num = "23648"
correct = 0
for x in range(len(computer_guesses)):
    for y in range(len(computer_guesses[x])):
        if num[y] == split(computer_guesses[x]):
            correct += 1
            print(correct)
        else:
            print(correct)
```

Comment: ```num[y] == split(computer_guesses[x])``` will always return false as you are comparing string with a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` for iterating on `iterable` with index counting.

```
computer_guesses = ["12345", "67890"]
num = "23648"
correct = 0
for guess in computer_guesses:
    for idx, digit in enumerate(guess):
        if num[idx] == digit:
            correct += 1
            print(correct)
        else:
            print(correct)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be one approach for your problem:

```
def split(num,word):
    num = num
    default = [char for char in num]
    wd = [char for char in word]
    correct = 0
    for m in range(len(wd)):
        if default[m]==wd[m]:
            correct += 1
    return correct


computer_guesses = ["12345", "67890"]
num = "23648"

for x in range(len(computer_guesses)):
    print(split(num, computer_guesses[x]))
```

Comment: Hi Tejas, thanks for the answer, I see what you have done but the output is not what I was looking for

Comment: what do you expect as output ?

Answer (score 0):

from my vision the **wrong part** in code it's **'if condition'** side

```
 if num[y] == split(computer_guesses[x]):
```

i switch it to :

```
if num[y] == computer_guesses[x][y]:
```

and the code working , i hope that what you looking for